# WPF Display a portion of bigger image in ImageBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm coming from Winforms trying to rewrite a program in WPF, and I want to display a certain portion of the whole image, depending on an Id I use for a list, that I load each portion of the whole image in. I was able to do it successfully in Winforms, but I want to perform the same task in WPF using Controls.Image. Heres what I did in Winforms.

```
PictureBox picBox;
List<Image> tileImageList;
Image FullImage;

public TileFrame(PictureBox pbox)
{        
    picBox = pbox;

    FullImage = picBox.Image; //The source of the picBox is set to the full image on init
    tileImageList = new List<Image>();

    PopTileList();
}

void PopTileList()
{
    const int SIZE = 32;
    Bitmap bitFullImage = new Bitmap(FullImage);

    for (int y = 0; y < 48; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++)
        {
            var portion = bitFullImage.Clone(new Rectangle((x * SIZE), (y * SIZE), SIZE, SIZE), bitFullImage.PixelFormat);

            tileImageList.Add(portion);             
        }
    }

    picBox.Image = tileImageList[10];//The first image that shows when this is done
}

public void ShowTilePic(int selectedId)
{            
    picBox.Image = tileImageList[--selectedId];         
}
```

Since the image being displayed will change based on the selected item of a listbox, the tileImageList is crucial for relating the list box selected index and the tileImageList index. Other answers I've searched for seemed to make it much more complicated than what I've done here. Is there a simple way to do this in WPF and in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm I figured it out.

```
List<CroppedBitmap> tileImageList;
Image imageBox;

public TileFrame(MainWindow mWindow)
{
    tileImageList = new List<CroppedBitmap>();
    imageBox = mWindow.ImageBox;

    PopTileList();
}

void PopTileList()
{
    const int SIZE = 32;

    var bitmapImage = (BitmapSource)imageBox.Source;         

    for (int y = 0; y < 48; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++)
        {
            var portion = new CroppedBitmap(bitmapImage, new Int32Rect((x * SIZE), (y * SIZE), SIZE, SIZE));                       
            tileImageList.Add(portion);                 
        }
    }        
}

public void ShowTilePic(int selectedId)
{
    imageBox.Source = tileImageList[selectedId];
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create 3072 CroppedBitmap and put them in list. Better just keep the source bitmap and create a single CroppedBitmap on the fly: `int y = selectedId / 64; int x = selectedId % 64; imageBox.Source = new CroppedBitmap(source, new Int32Rect((x * SIZE), (y * SIZE), SIZE, SIZE));`

Comment: It should greatly simplify your code without any performance or other negative impact.